# Ignite persistence performance hit and metrics

Tags: caching, persistence, ignite

I am trying out native persistence in Apache Ignite. My setup is currently local, single node cluster. I enabled it by adding this property in my data region

```
<property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
```

My full data region configuration is as follows

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
  <property name="name" value="dr.local.input.trade"/>
  <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
  <property name="metricsEnabled" value="true"/>
  <property name="initialSize" value="#{200 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
  <property name="maxSize" value="#{500 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
  <property name="pageEvictionMode" value="RANDOM_2_LRU"/>
</bean>
```

Now the entries are being persisted, i.e if I shutdown Ignite and restart it then my data comes back inside the cache.

I am seeing significant performance hit. Around 35% increased put operation latency compared to non-persisted data region. I have referred to Ignite persistence tuning page. From that I have singled out below properties and their properties

| Property | Value |
| --- | --- |
| WAL Modes | LOG_ONLY |
| walCompactionLevel | 3 |
| walCompationEnabled | true |
| writeThrottlingEnabled | true |
| checkpointBufferSize | 512 mb |
| checkpointFrequency | 5 minutes |

Is there anything more that I can tune? Is the performance hit I mentioned above is typical or can it be lowered much more?

Also I tried seeing JMX metrics related to persistence using JConsole. I was checking metrics under `org.apache.368239c8.ignitelocal."Persistent Store"`. All metrics mentioned under this are showing as 0. Data is surely persisted, I can see in Ignite work dir and WAL dir. Am I looking at wrong metrics? Please help.

Attaching entire Ignite config below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
Generated by Chef for ignite1.intranet.com
-->

<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

  <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_FALLBACK"/>
    <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <!-- Set to true to enable distributed class loading for examples, default is false. -->
    <property name="sslContextFactory">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.ssl.SslContextFactory">
          <property name="keyStoreFilePath" value="/home/sysSvcDevOps/ssl/ignite1.keystore.jks"/>
          <property name="keyStorePassword" value="KeyStore443"/>
          <property name="keyStoreType" value="jks"/>
          <property name="trustStoreFilePath" value="/home/sysSvcDevOps/ssl/cacerts/java.cacerts.jks"/>
          <property name="trustStorePassword" value="changeit"/>
          <property name="trustStoreType" value="jks"/>
      </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="igniteInstanceName" value=".dev"/>
    <property name="consistentId" value="ignite1.dev"/>
    <property name="workDirectory" value="/apps/Svc/dev/Ignite/IgniteData/persistentstore/work"/>

      <property name="rebalanceThreadPoolSize" value="8"/>
      <property name="publicThreadPoolSize" value="32"/>
      <property name="systemThreadPoolSize" value="64"/>
      <property name="queryThreadPoolSize" value="64"/>
      <property name="failureDetectionTimeout" value="30000"/>
      <property name="authenticationEnabled" value="true"/>
      <property name="metricsUpdateFrequency" value="30000"/>
      <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="false"/>
      <property name="clientMode" value="false"/>

    <!-- Enable task execution events for examples. -->
    <property name="includeEventTypes">
      <list>
        <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_STARTED"/>
        <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_STOPPED"/>
        <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_REBALANCE_PART_DATA_LOST"/>
        <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_NODES_LEFT"/>
      </list>
    </property>

    <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">

        <property name="walSegmentSize" value="1073741824"/>
          <property name="walSegments" value="20"/>
          <property name="maxWalArchiveSize" value="10737418240"/>
          <property name="walCompactionEnabled" value="true"/>
          <property name="walCompactionLevel" value="4"/>
          <property name="checkpointFrequency" value="300000"/>
          <property name="checkpointThreads" value="16"/>
          <property name="checkpointReadLockTimeout" value="60000"/>
          <property name="lockWaitTime" value="45000"/>
          <property name="checkpointWriteOrder" value="RANDOM"/>
          <property name="pageSize" value="4096"/>
          <property name="writeThrottlingEnabled" value="true"/>

        <!-- wal storage paths -->
        <property name="walPath" value="/apps/Svc/dev/Ignite/IgniteData"/>
        <property name="walArchivePath" value="/apps/Svc/dev/Ignite/IgniteDataArchive"/>
        <property name="storagePath" value="/apps/Svc/dev/Ignite/IgniteData/archive"/>

        <property name="dataRegionConfigurations">
          <list>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="dr.dev.referencedata"/>
                    <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                    <property name="initialSize" value="1073741824"/>
                    <property name="maxSize" value="4294969673"/>
                    <property name="checkpointPageBufferSize" value="1073741824"/>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="dr.dev.input"/>
                    <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                    <property name="metricsEnabled" value="true"/>
                    <property name="checkpointPageBufferSize" value="#{4 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                    <property name="initialSize" value="12884901888"/>
                    <property name="maxSize" value="81604378624"/>
                    <property name="pageEvictionMode" value="RANDOM_2_LRU"/>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="dr.dev.input.exception"/>
                    <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                    <property name="metricsEnabled" value="true"/>
                    <property name="checkpointPageBufferSize" value="#{4 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                    <property name="initialSize" value="4294967296"/>
                    <property name="maxSize" value="21474836480"/>
                    <property name="pageEvictionMode" value="RANDOM_2_LRU"/>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="dr.dev.output"/>
                    <property name="initialSize" value="1073741824"/>
                    <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                    <property name="metricsEnabled" value="true"/>
                    <property name="checkpointPageBufferSize" value="#{2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                    <property name="maxSize" value="2147483648"/>
                </bean>
          </list>
        </property>

        <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
              <property name="name" value="default_region"/>
              <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
              <property name="initialSize" value="268435456"/>
              <property name="maxSize" value="268435456"/>

          </bean>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="discoverySpi">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.zk.ZookeeperDiscoverySpi">
        <property name="zkConnectionString" value="zk1.intranet.com:22001,zk2.intranet.com:22001"/>
          <property name="zkRootPath" value="/ignite"/>
          <property name="sessionTimeout" value="120000"/>
          <property name="joinTimeout" value="10000"/>
      </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="communicationSpi">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
          <property name="socketWriteTimeout" value="60000"/>
      </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
      <list>
          <bean id="cache-template-bean" abstract="true"
                class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
              <property name="name" value="referenceDataCacheTemplate*"/>
              <property name="cacheMode" value="REPLICATED"/>
              <property name="backups" value="1"/>
              <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
              <property name="dataRegionName" value="dr.dev.referencedata"/>
              <property name="partitionLossPolicy" value="READ_WRITE_SAFE"/>
              <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="PRIMARY_SYNC"/>
              <property name="statisticsEnabled" value="true"/>
              <property name="sqlIndexMaxInlineSize" value="203"/>
            <property name="affinity">
              <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.rendezvous.RendezvousAffinityFunction">
                  <property name="partitions" value="256"/>


              </bean>
            </property>
          </bean>
          <bean id="cache-template-bean" abstract="true"
                class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
              <property name="name" value="inputMetadataCacheTemplate*"/>
              <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
              <property name="backups" value="1"/>
              <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
              <property name="dataRegionName" value="dr.dev.input"/>
              <property name="partitionLossPolicy" value="READ_WRITE_SAFE"/>
              <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="PRIMARY_SYNC"/>
              <property name="statisticsEnabled" value="true"/>
              <property name="readFromBackup" value="false"/>
              <property name="sqlIndexMaxInlineSize" value="211"/>
            <property name="affinity">
              <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.rendezvous.RendezvousAffinityFunction">
                  <property name="partitions" value="256"/>

                <property name="affinityBackupFilter">
                          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.rendezvous.ClusterNodeAttributeAffinityBackupFilter">
                            <constructor-arg>
                                                  <array value-type="java.lang.String">
                                                  <value>RACK_ID</value>
                                                     </array>
                             </constructor-arg>
                          </bean>
                </property>

              </bean>
            </property>
              <property name="expiryPolicyFactory">
                <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.ModifiedExpiryPolicy" factory-method="factoryOf">
                  <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration">
                      <constructor-arg value="DAYS"/>
                      <constructor-arg value="5"/>
                    </bean>
                  </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
              </property>
          </bean>
          <bean id="cache-template-bean" abstract="true"
                class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
              <property name="name" value="inputReconCacheTemplate*"/>
              <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
              <property name="backups" value="1"/>
              <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
              <property name="dataRegionName" value="dr.dev.input"/>
              <property name="partitionLossPolicy" value="READ_WRITE_SAFE"/>
              <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="PRIMARY_SYNC"/>
              <property name="statisticsEnabled" value="true"/>
              <property name="readFromBackup" value="false"/>
              <property name="sqlIndexMaxInlineSize" value="211"/>
            <property name="affinity">
              <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.rendezvous.RendezvousAffinityFunction">
                  <property name="partitions" value="256"/>

                <property name="affinityBackupFilter">
                          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.rendezvous.ClusterNodeAttributeAffinityBackupFilter">
                            <constructor-arg>
                                                  <array value-type="java.lang.String">
                                                  <value>RACK_ID</value>
                                                     </array>
                             </constructor-arg>
                          </bean>
                </property>

              </bean>
            </property>
              <property name="expiryPolicyFactory">
                <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy" factory-method="factoryOf">
                  <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration">
                      <constructor-arg value="DAYS"/>
                      <constructor-arg value="4"/>
                    </bean>
                  </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
              </property>
          </bean>
          <bean id="cache-template-bean" abstract="true"
                class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
              <property name="name" value="inputExceptionsCacheTemplate*"/>
              <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
              <property name="backups" value="1"/>
              <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
              <property name="dataRegionName" value="dr.dev.input.exception"/>
              <property name="partitionLossPolicy" value="READ_WRITE_SAFE"/>
              <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="PRIMARY_SYNC"/>
              <property name="statisticsEnabled" value="true"/>
              <property name="readFromBackup" value="false"/>
            <property name="affinity">
              <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.rendezvous.RendezvousAffinityFunction">
                  <property name="partitions" value="256"/>

                <property name="affinityBackupFilter">
                          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.rendezvous.ClusterNodeAttributeAffinityBackupFilter">
                            <constructor-arg>
                                                  <array value-type="java.lang.String">
                                                  <value>RACK_ID</value>
                                                     </array>
                             </constructor-arg>
                          </bean>
                </property>

              </bean>
            </property>
              <property name="expiryPolicyFactory">
                <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy" factory-method="factoryOf">
                  <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration">
                      <constructor-arg value="DAYS"/>
                      <constructor-arg value="15"/>
                    </bean>
                  </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
              </property>
          </bean>
          <bean id="cache-template-bean" abstract="true"
                class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
              <property name="name" value="outputDataCacheTemplate*"/>
              <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
              <property name="backups" value="1"/>
              <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
              <property name="dataRegionName" value="dr.dev.output"/>
              <property name="partitionLossPolicy" value="READ_WRITE_SAFE"/>
              <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="PRIMARY_SYNC"/>
              <property name="sqlSchema" value=""/>
              <property name="statisticsEnabled" value="true"/>
            <property name="affinity">
              <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.rendezvous.RendezvousAffinityFunction">
                  <property name="partitions" value="256"/>

                <property name="affinityBackupFilter">
                          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.rendezvous.ClusterNodeAttributeAffinityBackupFilter">
                            <constructor-arg>
                                                  <array value-type="java.lang.String">
                                                  <value>RACK_ID</value>
                                                     </array>
                             </constructor-arg>
                          </bean>
                </property>

              </bean>
            </property>
              <property name="expiryPolicyFactory">
                <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy" factory-method="factoryOf">
                  <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration">
                      <constructor-arg value="DAYS"/>
                      <constructor-arg value="450"/>
                    </bean>
                  </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
              </property>
          </bean>
          <bean id="cache-template-bean" abstract="true"
                class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
              <property name="name" value="reconAuditDataCacheTemplate*"/>
              <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
              <property name="backups" value="1"/>
              <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
              <property name="dataRegionName" value="dr.dev.referencedata"/>
              <property name="partitionLossPolicy" value="READ_WRITE_SAFE"/>
              <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="PRIMARY_SYNC"/>
              <property name="sqlSchema" value=""/>
              <property name="statisticsEnabled" value="true"/>
            <property name="affinity">
              <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.rendezvous.RendezvousAffinityFunction">
                  <property name="partitions" value="256"/>

                <property name="affinityBackupFilter">
                          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.rendezvous.ClusterNodeAttributeAffinityBackupFilter">
                            <constructor-arg>
                                                  <array value-type="java.lang.String">
                                                  <value>RACK_ID</value>
                                                     </array>
                             </constructor-arg>
                          </bean>
                </property>

              </bean>
            </property>
          </bean>
          <bean id="cache-template-bean" abstract="true"
                class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
              <property name="name" value="fileDataCacheTemplate*"/>
              <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
              <property name="backups" value="1"/>
              <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
              <property name="dataRegionName" value="dr.dev.input"/>
              <property name="partitionLossPolicy" value="READ_WRITE_SAFE"/>
              <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="PRIMARY_SYNC"/>
              <property name="statisticsEnabled" value="true"/>
              <property name="queryParallelism" value="4"/>
              <property name="eagerTtl" value="true"/>
            <property name="affinity">
              <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.rendezvous.RendezvousAffinityFunction">
                  <property name="partitions" value="256"/>

                <property name="affinityBackupFilter">
                          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.rendezvous.ClusterNodeAttributeAffinityBackupFilter">
                            <constructor-arg>
                                                  <array value-type="java.lang.String">
                                                  <value>RACK_ID</value>
                                                     </array>
                             </constructor-arg>
                          </bean>
                </property>

              </bean>
            </property>
              <property name="expiryPolicyFactory">
                <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy" factory-method="factoryOf">
                  <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration">
                      <constructor-arg value="DAYS"/>
                      <constructor-arg value="5"/>
                    </bean>
                  </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
              </property>
          </bean>
          <bean id="cache-template-bean" abstract="true"
                class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
              <property name="name" value="shortLivedReferenceDataTemplate*"/>
              <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
              <property name="backups" value="1"/>
              <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
              <property name="dataRegionName" value="dr.dev.input.exception"/>
              <property name="partitionLossPolicy" value="READ_WRITE_SAFE"/>
              <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="PRIMARY_SYNC"/>
              <property name="statisticsEnabled" value="true"/>
              <property name="managementEnabled" value="true"/>
            <property name="affinity">
              <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.rendezvous.RendezvousAffinityFunction">
                  <property name="partitions" value="64"/>

                <property name="affinityBackupFilter">
                          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.rendezvous.ClusterNodeAttributeAffinityBackupFilter">
                            <constructor-arg>
                                                  <array value-type="java.lang.String">
                                                  <value>RACK_ID</value>
                                                     </array>
                             </constructor-arg>
                          </bean>
                </property>

              </bean>
            </property>
              <property name="expiryPolicyFactory">
                <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy" factory-method="factoryOf">
                  <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration">
                      <constructor-arg value="DAYS"/>
                      <constructor-arg value="2"/>
                    </bean>
                  </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
              </property>
          </bean>

      </list>
    </property>

    <property name="sqlSchemas">
      <list>
        <value>dataInput</value>
      </list>
    </property>

  </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: What's your DataRegion configuration? Is its size remain the same as it used to be for in-memory config? Speaking of the metrics, you have to enable them explicitly. Is it only about writes or read operations are affected as well?

Comment: Edited my question, added data region config. I have enabled JMX metrics by providing JMX related JVM params. I can see all other metrics. I didnt get your question "Is its size remain the same as it used to be for in-memory config?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Speaking of the possible performance drop on writes.**

In comparison to a pure in memory mode, the following disk interactions happen on updates:

- in addition to a page modification in RAM, Ignite needs to provide consistency guarantees depending on your WAL mode, but unless it's not disabled, every update must be written to a WAL file. No data is flushed on disk yet; modification happens only in memory + WAL record is written.
- Once you have too many dirty pages in RAM, or a timeout occurs, Ignite starts a [checkpointing process](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/persistence/native-persistence#checkpointing) flushing dirty pages on disk to the partition files on disk.
- If WAL becomes too big, Ignite might perform segments rotation by copying them to a WAL archive to free up the space for new WAL updates.

As you can see, there are at least 3 major disk-related operations, meaning that it's crucial to have really fast disks for /wal, /walarchive and /db mounted folders. Again, it all depends on your use case, but in general it's strongly recommended to have the fastest available disks for WAL-related activity.

**Possible performance drop on reads.**

Again, it depends on a scenario, but if you can put all your data in memory (as it was before you turned persistence on), you will not see any performance differences.

It should be noted that after a restart, there will be no data in RAM at the start and Ignite must preload them first, i.e. to do a warm-up.

But, if you have more data than your configured data region size, a [page replacement](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/memory-configuration/replacement-policies#replacement-policies) will take place rotating the data from and to disk. Worse scenario: say, you have a 10 GB RAM data region and 11 GB dataset. And you want to scan your data twice in alphabetical order.

There was no data in RAM yet; imagine that you did a restart. Ignite starts to read data from the disk and populate the data pages in memory. Imagine that after the letter W, our in-memory data set became full, and page rotation is required to load the remaining W-Z data. In that case, the oldest pages need to be evicted - meaning that, say, A-D chunk needs to go to the disk to load W-Z data instead. So, your in-memory data set is now something like W-Z, E-V. If we are going to make the same scan query, the whole data set needs to be replaced similarly.

**Enable persistence metrics.**

Check that you have the following property in your data region configuration, more details [here](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring-metrics/configuring-metrics#enabling-persistence-related-metrics).

```
<property name="metricsEnabled" value="true"/>
```

Also, there is no need for

```
<property name="pageEvictionMode" value="RANDOM_2_LRU"/>
```

It's only for non-persistent regions.

Comment: Thanks for in-depth answer. I added `metricsEnabled=true` inside DR config, I still see nothing inside "Persistent Store" JMX section. Also I am really not understanding when WAL comes into effect. Even with non-persistent DRs I see WAL directory populated with segments.

Comment: Oh yes, that's true. WAL is written not only for persistence, but for in-memory as well.

Comment: any idea about why I cannot see persistence related metrics even after setting `metricsEnabled=true`?

Comment: I can think of the following: a) make sure your have metrics enabled for the concrete data region, i.e. this property is placed inside your  <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration"> and b) check that you are using the proper data region for metrics monitoring. If you have no caches configured for that region and its not persistent, I think you won't see any metrics.

Comment: If you still have an issue with getting the metrics, pls share your config, I'll take a look.

Comment: How should I share the entire config? I have a cache template bean which references DR which has `metricsEnabled=true` and I have couple of caches created using that template. So that metrics property should apply

Comment: Share it using pastebin or something? Anyway, my point is - for sure there might be some misconfiguration or a bug, but it works fine for me following the official docs.

Comment: Cannot access pastebin, restrictions. Have attached entire xml in my question

Comment: Tried your config. Created the following cache `ClientCache<Object, Object> cache = client.getOrCreateCache("inputReconCacheTemplateMy");`

 `cache.put(1, 1);` and added 5 simple items. Here is the result https://ibb.co/8NrLDmd

Comment: Other regions shows zeros, since there were no caches with data, like this https://ibb.co/GFt9H3F. I.e. your config seems good to me. Most likely you just didn't have data stored within the regions. Also, I tested it with Ignite 2.13. What's your version?

Comment: I saw your image. Those ones are from `DataRegionMetrics` metric group. Persistence related metrics are inside `Persistent Store` group. Please see if you can see metrics there.

Comment: Btw I saw one exception in log, probably that's why metrics collector thread may be dying? Here's a small portion of trace
`java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.pagemem.PageMemoryImpl.checkpointBufferPagesCount(PageMemoryImpl.java:1819) ~[ignite-core-2.9.0.jar!/:2.9.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.DataRegionMetricsImpl.getUsedCheckpointBufferPages(DataRegionMetricsImpl.java:296) ~[ignite-core-2.9.0.jar!/:2.9.0`

Comment: I see, in that case you need an extra step (enable metrics for DataStorageConfiguration)- <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
        <property name="metricsEnabled" value="true"/> . Result - https://ibb.co/5h7mSxw

Comment: Ignite 2.9.0 is quite old and most likely the mentioned error is a known issue and is already fixed. Anyway, I agree -  metrics configuration is confusing a lot. I suppose the documentation should be either extended or a code sample to be rewritten.

Comment: Speaking of the issue, seems to be https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-13770